# Why select asp-for has no value in post handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have this form on my page. It's for adding some project to DB. Project requires director for itself, so i pass SelectList of workers to this form.

```
<form asp-controller="Project" asp-action="Edit" method="post">
...some other fields...
@if (ViewBag.workers != null)
    {
        <div>
            <label asp-for="director">Director</label>
            <select asp-for="director" asp-items=@ViewBag.workers>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="director"></span>
        </div>
    }
...
</form>
```

Select tag working, there are my workers. But when i'm trying to submit, i have error "*The director field is required.*"

[image: form with error]

I've checked form with js and it has data from select option, but my post handler don't.
[image: handler argument]

There is code of hadler

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Edit(Project model)
    {
        // here model hasn't director field
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            dataManager.project.SaveProject(model);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), nameof(HomeController).Replace("Controller", ""));
        }
        ViewBag.workers = new SelectList(dataManager.worker.GetAllWorkers(), nameof(Worker.id), nameof(Worker.name));
        return View(model);
    }
```

And Project class code

```
public class Project
{
    [Required] public Guid id { set; get; }
    
    [Required] public string name { set; get; }
    
    public string customer { set; get; }

    public string executor { set; get; }

    public Worker director { set; get; }

    public DateTime start { set; get; }

    public DateTime end { set; get; }

    public uint priority { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is `director` is expecting a `Worker` object, but from View, you are posting the data with `director` is an id (example: integer/Guid type). Since both data types are unmatched, hence in the Controller side `director` is null as it is unable to unbind. What possible way that you can do this is to add a `DirectorId` property, View side pass the selected `DirectorId` to the controller. And controller query the `Director` object by `DirectorId` and map into `Project` object.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. but i had to remove `Director` field from `Project` and add `DirectorId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Post the solution mentioned in the comment as the answer post as the reference for the future reader.*

**Issue & Concern**

From this line:

```cs
ViewBag.workers = new SelectList(dataManager.worker.GetAllWorkers(), nameof(Worker.id), nameof(Worker.name));
```

You are setting the value of the drop-down list option as `id`. Unsure what is the `id` type, (possibly it is an `int`, `Guid` type) but I am sure that it is not a `Worker` (object) type.

While in the `Project` model, you specify `director` as `Worker` type.

```cs
public class Project
{
    ...

    public Worker director { set; get; }
}
```

Since an `int`/`Guid` type is unmatched with the `Worker` type, the API action is unable to bind the value that you passed from the View to the model. Thus, you will get `Project` as `null` in the API action.

---

**Solution**

1. Would suggest that modify the property type in `Project` model as `int`/`Guid` (depending on your Worker ID type in the database) rather than using the `Worker` (object) type. And remove the `Worker` property as it is no longer needed and avoid the error in `ModelState` due to the value is not provided.

*Note: If this `Project` model is the **entity model** that was generated (scaffolded) by Entity Framework, would suggest creating another class that acts as the DTO (Data Transfer Object). Then map the received DTO to entity model.*

```cs
public class Project
{
    ...

    public Worker directorId { set; get; }
}
```

2. In the View, bind the drop-down list with `asp-for="workerId"` to pass the selected value as `workerId`.

```
<select asp-for="directorId" asp-items=@ViewBag.workers></select>
```

3. Back-end side

   3.1. **Key point**: Query the `Worker` object with the received `project.workerId`. Then bind the `Worker` object to the entity model before inserting.

   3.2. (If implementing the DTO as mentioned in *1*) You need to implement the logic (or look for mapping library such as [AutoMapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/)) to map from DTO to the entity model.